# Alertdialog too small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alert dialog, I create with this:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundgeneral"
android:padding="10dp" <!-- editted -->
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMensajeAceptarDialogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/negro" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAceptarDialogo"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_rojo"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="-1"
            android:shadowRadius="0.1"
            android:text="Aceptar"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConfirmarVisita.this).create();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutdialogoaceptar, null);
TextView mensaje = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMensajeAceptarDialogo);
mensaje.setText("Visita confirmada");
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
alerta.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

Button btnAceptar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAceptarDialogo);
btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alerta.dismiss();
        Intent detalleServicio = new Intent(Contexto, DetalleServicio.class);
        detalleServicio.putExtra("codigo_parcela_servicio", servicioRecogido);
        startActivity(detalleServicio);
     }
});
alerta.setView(view);              
alerta.show();
```

But when it show its too small:

[image: toosmall]

What am I doing wrong? I try to set 500dp for width and height but I have the same result.

And question 2, how can I remove the white border? I think the 2 problems are the same but I'm not sure.

Comment: With padding works ok, but how can i remove the lareatal, top and bottom white margin?

Answer (score 3):

```
Display dm = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int width = dm.getWidth();
    final int height = dm.getHeight();
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height/2);
```

You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

try like this Alert Dialog Box

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ContactList.this);

        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("your title");

        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                         //your stuffs
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

This might help you

Comment: The size its ok, but i cant remove the white margin.

Comment: Yes bit u have the same result, but this only happend me on galaxy tab 8.9 or 10.1..Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:layout_height` to some value for base `LinearLayout`.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    <!-- right here -->
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:background="@drawable/backgroundgeneral"
    android:padding="10dp" <!-- editted -->
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```